# Batch downloading available pages in Google books?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, firefox-extensions

I am using [Google Book Downloader](http://book.huhiho.com/) addon to Firefox. It generates links to individual image per available page, but if I would like to download multiple pages' images using selecting the links and right-clicking "DownloadThemAll! Selection..." in Firefox, I will be notified that that the image files all have the same name "books".

The links generated by [Google Book Downloader](http://book.huhiho.com/) addon are shown under different text names based on their page numbers. So I wonder if there is a way to batch download the image files with their names automatically changed to their page numbers, and therefore resolving the same name conflict.

PS:

1. My operating system is Ubuntu.
2. The source code of the [Google Book Downloader](http://book.huhiho.com/) addon is
   [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/37933).